# Kotlin Android Studio Unused Import Directive

Tags: android, kotlin

Coming from Swift/iOS to android Kotlin and trying to understand why my imports are becoming "unused".

I am using the book "Android Studio Development Essentials". I think the problem is because in the book they want me to create a a "Java Source Language" activity, yet the code in the book is for Kotlin and not Java (I believe a mistake in the book) because none of the statements in the example for the "Java Source Language" activity have the semi-colon ";". So I decided to create a Kotlin activity instead.

Im pretty sure for a "Java Source Language" that the code for the imports should have semi-colons yet in the book they do not.

**ActivityA**
[image]

**ActivityB**
[image]

Comment: It seems that those imports are really not being used.

Comment: In Kotlin, the semi-colon is as optional as it is in Swift. Java is the Objective-C of Android these days. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an import is `unused` that means the import classes that said import bring to the classpath are not used in the current file/class.

Let's look at two examples from your Screenshot:

`View`:
In your 1st screenshot, you have a reference to `View` in the `onClick(View view)` method.

In your second screenshot, that code is gone, so there's no need to keep the `View` import if you're not going to use it.

`Intent`:
The 1st sshot shows a constructor invocation for Intent (`var i = Intent(...)...`), said invocation is gone in the 2nd sshot; no need to keep the package either.

Keep in mind Kotlin does a lot of *magic* and *syntax sugaring* behind and not-so-behind the scenes, so even though you may be *using* Views and Intents, the fact that you don't need to type those, means you don't need the imports either.

If Java (or Kotlin) needs to access those, you will need to import it and you will know when that's the case because your code will not compile.

Now the last one `synthetic...` is part of the Kotlin Extensions (if I am not mistaken) and it's basically referencing your widgets/views from the layout.

In that case, `activity_b.xml` likely. You no longer reference that in your code, so, import is gone.

I recommend you do a `control` + `alt` + `o` (replace `control` with `command` if you're on macOS, and remember `alt` is called `option` on Mac hardware), quite often. It's an Optimize Imports feature of Android Studio that will clean it up for you :)

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. This book is just throwing me for a loop because I am following the instructions yet the code doesn't compile. Maybe I just need to throw this book out lol

Comment: Depending how old the book is, there are plenty of good tutorials/other books online to learn Android Development (and Kotlin if that's your desire). If the book is 2 or more years old, I'd say, keep it as reference, but rather find something newer. Android pace is moving fast (and so is iOS and other techs in general), so paper books that are too constrained by what they want to teach, are almost always outdated before they are even printed, sadly.

Comment: This is the Android Studio 3.0 Development Essentials 8th edition. Says Copyrighted 2017 after the first page so I think you're right.... Sadness begins lol

Comment: I'd say keep an eye for things coming from [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/android) for example. Or even Google's own [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals) documentation, which is a great starting point to understand the Android framework.